# How come a variable in a function is able to reference from outside it's scope?

Tags: python, function, scope

In this case, the "all_lines" variable is initalised in the context manager, and it is accessible from the function "part_1".

```
total = 0
with open("advent_input.txt", "r") as txt:
    all_lines = []
    context_total = 0
    for line in txt:
        all_lines.append((line.rstrip().split(" ")))


def part_1():
    # total = 0
    for line in all_lines:
        if line[0] == "A":
            if line[1] == "Y":
                total += 8
            elif line[1] == "X":
                context_total += 4
```

However, "context_total", which is also initalised in the context manager, does not work in the function "part_1". And "total" from the global scope does not work either. How come "all_lines" works?

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have general block scope, so anything assigned within the `with` will be accessible outside of the block.

`context_total` is different though since you're reassigning it within the function. If you assign within a function, the variable will be treated as a local unless you use `global` to specify otherwise. That's problematic here though since `+=` necessarily must refer to an existing variable (or else what are you adding to?), but there is no local variable with that name.

Add `global context_total` to use it within the function, or pass it in as an argument if you don't need the reassigned value externally.

Answer (score 0):

It works because inside the function, the `all_lines` variable is *referenced* but not *assigned*.  The other two variables are *assigned*.

If a variable is *assigned* inside a function, then that variable is treated as local throughout the function, even if there is a global variable of the same name.